# Why can't I select my value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

It's really frustrating. I've always used .val() like this, but now it doesn't work.

I'm using jQuery v1.7.2.

I have a facebox box which I initiate with a hidden value so I know what value I should change on the main page when facebox is done.

I have this HTML code:

`<hidden type="hidden" value="hello" id="testid" name="testname" />`

And in jQuery I've logged:

```
console.log($('[name="testname"]'));
console.log($('#testid'));
console.log($('#testid').val());
console.log($('[name="testname"]').val());
```

And this outputs:

```
[<hidden type=​"hidden" value=​"hello" id=​"testid" name=​"testname">​</hidden>​]
[<hidden type=​"hidden" value=​"hello" id=​"testid" name=​"testname">​</hidden>​]
(empty line)
(empty line)
```

So why cant I access this value?

I'm using facebox with AJAX and I know that if I use facebox with divs it will copy the dom element so that I get two with same IDs but this shouldnt happend with AJAX? And also then I would get more elements returned on the first two lines, wouldnt I?
A strange thing is if I inspect the elements in Chrome I see that the input box has changed to:

```
<hidden type="hidden" value="hello" id="testid" name="testname"></hidden>
```

But maybe that doesn't matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no element hidden. Do you mean `<input type="hidden">`?

If you actually want to use a custom element, I believe you will have to use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```
console.log($('#testid').prop("value"));
```

Comment: Thanks!

It was not my intetion to have that type, I wanted input type, but was starring myself blind on other thing so I didnt see the obvious mistake:) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There is no `<hidden>` element in HTML, so jQuery doesn't have the special handling needed to support its `val()` method.

You want `<input>`. It is generally a good idea to run your HTML through an automated [validator](http://validator.w3.org) that can pick up this type of error.

(You could also use `attr('value')` but writing valid HTML is a much better idea)